# ListView Requires 2 setSelection's to Scroll to Item

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter, android-listfragment

Peculiar problem I'm having with a cursoradapter in a listfragment.

In my onLoadFinished I select the previously selected item in order to scroll the listview to the previous position (and then highlight that item).

This works splendidly, except for the scrolling part.

**If I just use one post and delay it (even say 5 seconds), the item gets selected but the list will not scroll (the selected item may out of view at this time)**  With or without delay same behavior with just one post.

I have to post setSelection AGAIN to get the listview to scroll so the selected item is in view.

It doesn't matter how long I delay the initial or second scroll post.

Here's my grubby workaround, but I'm not pleased with it.  Any ideas?

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    getListView().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getListView().requestFocusFromTouch();
            getListView().setSelection(selectedposition);
            getListView().performItemClick(getListView().getAdapter().getView(selectedposition, null, null), selectedposition, selectedid);
            getListView().clearFocus();
        }    
    });
    getListView().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getListView().requestFocusFromTouch();
            getListView().setSelection(selectedposition);
            getListView().performItemClick(getListView().getAdapter().getView(selectedposition, null, null), selectedposition, selectedid);
            getListView().clearFocus();
        }    
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: did you try commenting out one of each of those set selection methods to see if anything different happens? Or did you just post the second one and then just see it work? If not try commenting out one of each and tell what happens.

Comment: @redelman431.  Sorry for the confusion, yes I did try this already, quoted from my question:  "If I just use one post and delay it (even say 5 seconds), the item gets selected but the list will not scroll ..." unless I post a second time.

Comment: So same thing happens if you comment out either one?

Comment: @redelman431 Yes that is correct. And per my question it doesn't matter how long I delay.  I can even postdelay 5 or 10 seconds and still no scrolling, just the item gets selected with one post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rewrite:**

> If I take them out of the runnable it works with calling setselection just once. However then I don't get a delayed scrolling effect (to show the user it scrolled), which I guess I sorta like.

When I took a closer look at your code I noticed that you were calling `getView()` in the Adapter manually. Adapters recycle their views in a very particular but unpredictable order and attempting to call `getView()` yourself might create unwanted behavior... You should avoid doing this, try a different tactic:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data); // or changeCursor(data) as explained below
    getListView().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ListView listView = getListView(); // Save a local reference rather than calling `getListView()` three times
            listView.setSelection(selectedposition);
            listView.performItemClick(listView.getChildAt(0), selectedposition, selectedposition);
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: thanks.  Interesting, if I take them out of the runnable it works with calling setselection just once.  However then I don't get a delayed scrolling effect (to show the user it scrolled), which I guess I sorta like.  But when I put those in a posted runnable with or without focus it still doesn't scroll unless i post a second time.

Comment: That is interesting, I'll play with that myself. I wanted to point out the `swapCursor()` doesn't close the previous Cursor, while `changeCursor()` does. If you did this intentionally (or only use one Cursor) that's fine, but otherwise you should use `changeCursor()` to free these unused resources.

Comment: Thank you again.  I looked it over after eating some food and asked myself why I was calling getlistview multiple times, brain must have needed energy.   The LV won't scroll at all if setselection is inside a posted runnable until I call it a second time (either in or out of a runnable).  If I take the setselection out of the posted runnable it scrolls the first time (without having to call setselection again), but then I don't get the scroll affect.  I'm only using one cursor BTW...

Comment: Also listView.getChildAt(0) throws a nullpointer and .getView does not.

Comment: `listView.getChildAt()` can only be run after the ListView has been drawn, so it must be called in a Runnable via `post()` or `postDelayed()`. It also assume that your ListView is not empty...

Comment: i do a check for empty listview, and with getchildat in a posted runnable i still get a null.  maybe onloadfinished is not the right place for setselection.  anyways you've been tremendous help, i think i'm happy with the setselection out of the posted runnable, it is cleaner even though i'm not getting the scroll affect.  thanks again.